# Interpret byte stream c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, byte

I'm receiving 7 hex bytes via serial, for instance:

90 50 **01 0e 0c 00** ff

The bold part is the information I need. To read the bytes and print to the terminal, this is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    posBuffer[i] = SP1.ReadByte();
    Console.WriteLine(posBuffer[i]);
}
```

What I'm trying now, is to extract the `4` bytes I need, then combine them and print them as one decimal number. In the above example, I would need `7872` in the *decimal* value (`1ec0` converted to *decimal*)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How about [How to convert a byte array to an int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-an-int)

Comment: Why `1e c0` and not `01 0e 0c 00`?

Comment: not sure I understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to aggregate `4` *lower nibbles* from each byte of `posBuffer` starting from index `2`:

```
   0x90, 0x50, 0x01, 0x0e, 0x0c, 0x00, 0xff
                  |     |     |     | 
                  1     e     c     0 => 0x1ec0 => 7872 (decimal)
```

If it's your case, you can try Linq `Aggregate`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int result = posBuffer
  .Skip(2)
  .Take(4)
  .Aggregate(0, (total, item) => (total << 4) | (item & 0xF));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do that is the following i think.

```
var values = { posBuffer[0], posBuffer[1], posBuffer[2], posBuffer[3] };

var position = BitConverter.ToInt32(values, 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work sadly. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Not getting 7872 anyway :(